# Setting the icons of resources associated with my application using a plist (cocoa osx)

Tags: cocoa, macos, plist

My application creates some xml files that are proprietary to my application and I would like to associate these file types with my application, originally I set the icons of newly created files using setIcon:forFile:options: but it seems like I should be using a plist instead.  In the documentation I found how to set the icon of the application itself but I could not find any description about how to set icons of other associated file types.  Could anyone link me to such info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are more general and provide background info:

[Information Property List Files](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPRuntimeConfig/Articles/ConfigFiles.html)

[About Information Property List Files](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html)

These are specific to document types:

[CFBundleDocumentTypes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009249-101685-TPXREF107)

[Storing Document Types Information in the Application's Property List](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Documents/Concepts/DocTypePList.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000024)

Answer (score 2):

Apple provides an overview on the topic [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010411-SW1). For a breakdown of available keys see [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009249-SW1).

As an example:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>typename</string>

        <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
        <array>
            <string>ext</string>
        </array>

        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
        <string>icon.icns</string>

        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>

        <key>LSTypeIsPackage</key>
        <false />

        <key>NSPersistentStoreTypeKey</key>
        <string>Binary</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```